# How do I get the last row of a group in a DataFrame based on certain values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following data:

```
PersID    Date   FirmID   Start   End   Match
     1    2017      100    2016  2017       1
     1    2017      200    2017  2019       1
     1    2018      200    2017  2019       1
     2    2016      600    2014  2017       1
     2    2017      600    2014  2017       1
     2    2017      700    2017  2017       1
     2    2017      800    2017  2019       1
```

I want:

```
PersID    Date   FirmID   Start   End   Match
     1    2017      200    2017  2019       1
     1    2018      200    2017  2019       1
     2    2016      600    2014  2017       1
     2    2017      800    2017  2019       1
```

I am trying to get the last observation for each PersID and Date. The FirmID, Start, and End date are irrelevant in that I don't care to filter on that information. But I do want to keep that data.

I have tried using:

```
df.groupby(['PersID', 'Date'])['match'].last()
```

That yields:

```
PersID    Date   Match
     1    2017       1
     1    2018       1
     2    2016       1
     2    2017       1
```

It's almost there, but I want to keep the rest of the data too. Any solutions?

Comment: Try without `"match"`? `df.groupby(['PersID', 'Date']).last()`?

Comment: Well that was easy. That then changes the index to PersID and Date. How do I change that?

Comment: Try `df.groupby(["PersID", "Date"], as_index=False).last()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @Chris in the comments, the solution is:

```
df.groupby(["PersID", "Date"], as_index=False).last()
```